# Loading images from external mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, ios, image, performance

i know this questions is posed many times but i haven't found a solution yet.

I am creating an IOS app which connects to an external MYSQL database table and retrieves data.
the table in the DB has multiple columns and one of them is called "Image" which contains the URL of the image. 
What i am trying to do is create a PHP script that takes this URL transforms it into image and encodes it to Base64. And after doing so i retrieve it from the IOS app.

The problem is that it is Very slow.
first i tried selecting only the URL and then loading the URL image directly from the app and it has proven to be much slower.
then i tried to encode it to Base64 and from the iPhone app i decode it to display the image which is also very slow (7 minutes to retrieve 50 rows).

Is there any way i could speed it up? and how?

Comment: Why not just a simple `img src="'.$row['image'].'"`?

Comment: i want to display the image in the app. $row['image'] would return the image URL. i want to find an optimised way to retrieve the image without having to wait 6 to 10 minutes to display the content in the app

Comment: Not if you use `<img src`, which has been around since the dawn of web browser time. The "waiting" part I don't quite get, are your images large? Do you have any unwanted loops in DB? It's the encoding part that's most likely taking the most time.

Comment: what format are the images> gif, jpg, png, bmp (hopefully not)?

Comment: some are jpg and some are png.

Comment: which ones are slower? if one format is slower than the other, make them all the one that's faster.